# jQuery - Get text inside tag and use it as a css rule

Tags: jquery, css

Let's say I have this HTML:

```
    <ul>
       <li>
           <a>Item one</a>
           <small>#000000</small>
           <span class="corner"></span>
       </li>
       <li>
           <a>Item two</a>
           <small>#ffffff</small>
           <span class="corner"></span>
       </li>
    </ul>
```

I want to get the text between the span tag, and apply it as a background color to the 'span' inside the same 'li'.

So what I tried is:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    $("span.corner").addClass("custom-color"); //apply class custom-color to span


     if ($("span.corner").hasClass("custom-color")) { //if the span.corner has custom-color class do the next

           var cornerColor = $('.corner').prev('small').text(); //this should get the text between the 'small' tags

            if (cornerColor !== '') { //if there is some text between 'small' tags, apply it as a css rule to the 'corner.span'
                $('.corner').css('background-color', cornerColor);
            }
        }
});
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work, it applies the 'custom-color' class but then it does not apply the css rule. If I replace the variable cornerColor to an actual color, it does. So I guess the error is in the variable to get the text inside the span. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `var cornerColor = $('.corner').prev('small').text();` you are taking a text of all `small` tags concatenated. So basically `cornerColor  = "#000000#fffff"`; which is obviously not valid.

```
$("span.corner").addClass("custom-color"); //apply class custom-color to span
if ($("span.corner").hasClass("custom-color")) { 
  $('.corner').prev('small').each(function(){
    var cornerColor = $(this).text(); 
    if (cornerColor !== '') {
      $(this).next('.corner').css('background-color', cornerColor);
    }
  });
}
```

Code above uses .each to go through each small tag, takes it inner text and apply to `span.corner` next to it. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4Su4G/1/

Comment: Thank you very much for your clear example and explanation, I got it now. Can I accept multiple answers?

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $("li").each(function(){
        $(this).find("span.corner").addClass("custom-color"); //apply class custom-color to span
        if ($(this).find("span.corner").hasClass("custom-color")) {
            var cornerColor = $(this).find('small').text();
            if (cornerColor) {
                $(this).find("span.corner").css('background-color', cornerColor);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I spent the last 3 hours on it and you fixed it in 3 mins. Works, also got why. Thanks mate.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
 $("span.corner").addClass("custom-color"); //apply class custom-color to span
 if ($("span.corner").hasClass("custom-color")) {
   $('span.corner').each(function () {
     var cornerColor = $(this).prev('small').html();
     if (cornerColor) {
     $(this).css('background-color', cornerColor);
     }
   });
 }
});
```

See this : http://jsfiddle.net/nN6Nd/2/